# How do I fail a Jenkins build if a Docker Pipeline Plugin withRun command returns a non-zero exit code?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using the [Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin) to execute my build scripts via Docker containers. I noticed that if I had a script return a non-zero exit code when executing within an `inside()` command, Jenkins would mark the pipeline execution as a failure. This example Jenkinsfile illustrates that scenario:

```
docker.image('alpine').inside() {
  sh 'exit 1'
}
```

However, if I use the `withRun()` command, a similar Jenkinsfile will *not* cause the build to fail, even though the `docker ps -l` command shows that the container exited with a non-zero status:

```
node() {
  sh 'touch ./test.sh'
  sh 'echo "exit 1" >> ./test.sh'
  sh 'chmod 755 ./test.sh'

  docker.image('alpine').withRun("-v ${WORKSPACE}:/newDir", '/bin/sh /newDir/test.sh') {container ->
    sh "docker logs ${container.id} -f"
    sh 'docker ps -l'
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make `withRun()` fail the build if the container exits with a non-zero code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any more information on exit codes from the `withRun()` command, so I ended up just executing a `docker run` command from an `sh` step:

```
node() {
  sh 'touch ./test.sh'
  sh 'echo "exit 1" >> ./test.sh'
  sh 'chmod 755 ./test.sh'
  sh "docker run --rm -v ${WORKSPACE}:/newDir alpine /bin/sh /newDir/test.sh"
}
```

Comment: Hacky solution, better to fully use the Image.run() function

Answer (score 4):

One of possible solutions:

```
docker.withRegistry("https://${REGISTRY}", 'creds-id') {

    stage("RUN CONTAINER"){
        Image = docker.image("${IMAGE}-${PROJECT}:${TAG}")
        try {
            c = Image.run("-v /mnt:/mnt")
            sh "docker logs -f ${c.id}"
            def out = sh script: "docker inspect ${c.id} --format='{{.State.ExitCode}}'", returnStdout: true
            sh "exit ${out}"
        } finally {
            c.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP. Your solution works around what seems to be a critical deficiency in the Jenkins Docker pipeline plugin's `run` and `withRun` method: they do not return the container's exit code. Is this still the case as far as you know? Or is this manual "run + inspect + cleanup" still the only way to solve this? I'm very surprised the Docker pipeline plugin doesn't natively support this -- it seems absolutely critical that you would always want to know the exit code from your container.

Answer (score 1):

How about running a script that exits based upon the output from [`docker wait`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/)?

```
sh "exit \$(docker wait ${container.id})"
```

`wait` prints the container's exit code, which in case of error causes the build to fail according to [sh docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script):

> Normally, a script which exits with a nonzero status code will cause the step to fail with an exception.