# Run commands inside Docker container without mounting project directory

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline uses the [`docker-workflow`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin) plugin. It builds a Docker image and tags it `app`. The build step fetches some dependencies and bakes them into the image along with my app.

I want to run two commands inside a container based on that image. The command should be executed in the built environment, with access to the dependencies. I tried using `Image.inside`, but it seems to fail because `inside` mounts the project directory over the working directory (?) and so the dependencies aren't available.

```
docker.image("app").inside {
    sh './run prepare-tests'
    sh './run tests'
}
```

I tried using `docker.script.withDockerContainer` too, but the commands don't seem to run inside the container. The same seems to be true for `Image.withRun`. At least with that I could specify a command, but it seems that I'd have to run specify both commands in one statement. Also it seems that [`withRun` doesn't fail the build if the command doesn't exit cleanly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44687787/320036).

```
docker
  .image("app")
  .withRun('', 'bash -c "./app prepare-tests && ./app tests"') { container ->
    sh "exit \$(docker wait ${container.id})"
  }
```

Is there a way to use `Image.inside` without mounting the project directory? Or is there are more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

`docker` DSL, like `docker.image().inside() {}` etc will mount jenkins job workspace dir to container and make it as the `WORKDIR` which will overwrite the `WORKDIR` in Dockerfile.

You can verify that from jenkins console output .

1) `CD` workdir fristly

```
docker.image("app").inside {
    sh '''
        cd <WORKDIR of image specifyed in Dockerfile>
        ./run prepare-tests
        ./run tests
    '''
}
```

2) Run container in `sh` , rather than via `docker` DSL

```
sh '''
    docker run -i app bash -c "./run prepare-tests && ./run tests"
'''
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well! I also found that I had to tell it to use the `root` user, since that's who owns the files in the image. Like this: `.inside('-u root:root') {...}`